# SQLite: rawQuery() doesn't work but execSQL() works

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following code. When I open my `SQLite` db I can see the patient with `Id = 1235` is created but not with `Id = 1234`:

```
String sql;
sql = "INSERT INTO Users(Id, Name, Surname, LastLogin)VALUES(1234, 'john', 'foo', null)";
database.rawQuery(sql, null);

sql = "INSERT INTO Users(Id, Name, Surname, LastLogin)VALUES(1235, 'john', 'foo', null);";
database.execSQL(sql);
```

The documentation for `rawQuery()` states:

> the SQL query. The SQL string must **not** be **;** terminated

and this is indeed the case in my 1st query. (the other difference is the `Id`. I changed it so that both inserts could work, `Id` is index).

Using the debugger I can confirm that both queries are executed and I don't get any exceptions or errors.

Any idea? I have spent hours on this but I could not figure it out. I guess it is something very trivial that I am missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though I cannot find this in the documentation, what I understand is that rawQuery is meant for SELECT queries. It is just a "raw" interface to what "query" methods do.

Answer (score 10):

```
public void execSQL (String sql)
```

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data.

You have to use `execSQL()` for

- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE

Use `rawQuery()`  as it returns `Cursor` for `SELECT` queries.

Answer (score 3):

You must put:

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
c.moveToFirst();
c.close();
```

Comment: An INSERT cannot return anything for a cursor.

Comment: @CL. This will actually work. Think of `rawQuery()` as C API `sqlite3_prepare*()` and `moveToFirst()` as `sqlite3_step()` and it runs the SQL, even though the cursor itself doesn't contain anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO Users(Id, Name, Surname, LastLogin) VALUES(1234, 'john', 'foo', null)", null);
```

And let me know if it works or not ?

Comment: That would not compile because first argument of `rawQuery()` should be a `String`